# C++11 Pack expansion argument assignment y member initialization error compile

Tags: templates, c++11, template-meta-programming

I have been develop a generic queue, but I am failing in the wrapper that will content the different implementations of the queue (linked list, fixed stack)
For that reason I need to use variadic template to capture the different parameters that the different list are built in.
here is a example code that is not the implementation (is not finish):

```
template<typename containner,typename ... Arg>
struct GenericMultiType
{};
template<template<typename ...> class  containner, typename ... Arg>
struct GenericMultiType<containner<Arg ...>, Arg ... >
{
    GenericMultiType(const Arg & ... aValue ):Value(aValue ) ...
    {}
    void getValue( Arg  & ... aValue)
    {
        aValue=Value;
    }
    Arg ... Value ;
    containner<Arg ...> Containner;
};


int main()
{
}
```

And This is the compiler out error:

```
error: expected unqualified-id before '...' token
     Arg ... Value ;
         ^
main.cpp: In constructor 'GenericMultiType<containner<Arg ...>, Arg ...>::GenericMultiType(const Arg& ...)':
main.cpp:105:47: error: class 'GenericMultiType<containner<Arg ...>, Arg ...>' does not have any field named 'Value'
     GenericMultiType(const Arg & ... aValue ):Value(aValue ) ...
                                               ^
```

Comment: You can't have a pack expansion there. Use `std::tuple` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Arg ...` is a pack expansion and doesn't constitute a type. What you are looking for is `std::tuple<Arg...>`. So, you would make your `Value` the appropriate tuple. Here's the modified code:

```
template<typename containner,typename ... Arg>
struct GenericMultiType
{};
template<template<typename ...> class  containner, typename ... Arg>
struct GenericMultiType<containner<Arg ...>, Arg ... >
{
    using value_type = typename std::tuple<Arg...>;
    GenericMultiType(Arg&& ... aValue ): Value(std::make_tuple(std::forward<Arg>(aValue)...)
    {}
    void getValue(value_type& aValue)
    {
        aValue=Value;
    }
    value_type Value ;
    containner<Arg ...> Containner;
};
```

Comment: thx! that the solution. Also i have received the comment that this can be done doing the partial specialization of the base template. Is that comment true? thx in advance